# Which domain need to be whitelisted for a sheets add-on using a third party library in drive and docs setting in google workspace?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have installed a google sheet add on, which uses https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2 library for authentication. I am able to install the add on without any issues but once I try to login I am getting this error.

> Library with identifier OAuth2 is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)

[Library with identifier OAuth2 is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOcIa.png)
So I tried a couple of settings in the admin console and I figured out that there is a setting which is working.
[Functional drive and docs sharing setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkBp5.png)
But I don't want folks outside our org to be able to share drive files with us, so we have restricted it to domains we recognise for security reasons.
[Restricted drive and docs sharing setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWcIZ.png)
Now this setting is throwing the above read access error message, is there a way to solve this with our restricted "drive and docs" sharing setting?, which domain can we whitelist to avoid the above error?, where are the third party libraries in apps script accessed from.
I tried whitelisting domains below, but these do not seem to work.
[whitelisted domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWCmo.png)

Comment: Did you install an Add-on that you developed yourself or from a third party? If the latter - then contact the developer of the Add-on and explain him the problem.

Comment: Yes the add has been developed by us.

Comment: In this case, please provide a functioning sample code that would help to troubleshoot the issue.